# How to change the url according to the combobox value in mvc3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, routes

When I change the page path, like this:
 localhost/XXX/fr - the page is in french 
and when I write:
 localhost/XXX/en - the page is in english.
 (the text is taken from the resources files).

I also have a combobox contains "english" with value=en
 and "french" with value="fr".

now, How do I get the URL change by the selected value?
 I was thinking that maybe i sould write something like-

```
controllerName/.../theSelectedValue
```

but I dont know how to do this.

(the value selected is = `$("#combobox")[0].value` in JQuery, Can I write it in JQuery?)

---

I actualy did this:

```
var urlString = window.location.host;   //the url with localhost:XXX only -and if it changes it will adjust itself 

var Lang = $(this)[0].value;            //en or fr
window.location = "http://" + urlString + "/" + Lang;
```

but now I have another problem: window.location - refreshes the page, and the $(this)[0].value - returns to be as the beginning. for example if I change the combobox from "english" to "french", the language does change to french (coz the url isnt refreshed), but in the combobox, the selected field is "english" again and I cant change it because all the page is refreshed.
so...is anybody can tell me what to do??

thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to the [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event for the combobox, like this:

```
$('#CLIENT_ID_FOR_YOUR_CHECKBOX_HERE').change(function() {
  window.location = "http://localhost/XXX/" + $(this).val();
});
```